# Performance StringBuilder vs concatenation

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, concatenation, stringbuilder

I tested a simple concatenation:

```
 string res = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
     res += mystring;     
 }
 return res;
```

and another with a `StringBuilder` object:

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
     builder.Append(mystring);           
 }
 return builder.ToString();
```

The bigger is the cycle, the better are the performances using the `StringBuilder`.

I would like to know the real reason of this result, I mean, that fact of creating, implementing an object, calling methods is faster than a simple `string1 + string2`?

Comment: Read Jon Skeet's [Concatenating Strings Efficiently](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable, so each `+= mystring` creates a new object. In the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) case you're operating on one instance, hence the performance difference. You can improve the performance further by configuring the `Capacity` property. You can find more information on this issue in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).